# How to get a scheduler and AMQP to work together properly in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amqp, eventmachine, rufus-scheduler

What I want to do is start a recurring process that every hour publishes a batch of messages to a RMQ exchange on our server.

I have a class, let's call it `RMQProcess`, that fires up an AMQP event loop. I thought that I could use rufus-scheduler to do this:

```
scheduler.every '10s', :times=>6 do
  process = RMQProcess.new
  process.start
end

scheduler.join
```

This works...except each time through the loop, the AMQP channel increases (from 2 to 4 to 6 etc...). I think this means the channels are not being closed properly, which could present a problem.

I guess to summarize my question, what is the proper (or at least a proper) way to do this sort of thing? Should the AMQP process be fired up before entering the scheduler process or am I doing it the right way? Do I have to roll my own scheduling logic inside the AMQP event loop? That is my fear, because it seems like there must be a better way. Any advice appreciated.

For reference, here is the start method (in this case I'm just publishing nonsense sentences using the RandomText gem):

```
def start
    begin
      puts @rmq_params
      AMQP.start(@rmq_params) do 
        |connection|

        connection.on_error do
          |ch, connection_close|
          puts "#{connection_close.reply_text}"
        end

        connection.on_tcp_connection_loss do
          |conn, settings|
          puts "[network failure] Trying to reconnect..."
          conn.reconnect(false, 2)
        end

        channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection, :auto_recovery => true)
        puts "Channel ID = #{channel.id}"
        exchange = channel.direct(@exchangeName,:durable => true)
        exchange.publish(Lorem.words)

        EM.add_timer(@duration) do
            connection.close do
                EM.stop_event_loop
            end
        end


        Signal.trap("INT") do
          connection.close do
            EM.stop_event_loop
          end
        end

      end
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "#{e.message} #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
6.times do
  process = RMQProcess.new
  process.start
  sleep(10)
end
```

behave differently?

If I were you I'd "start" AMQP outside of RMQProcess#start and re-use the resulting connection.